# How to set the old value which was selected earlier, after a value change event fired

Tags: vaadin7

I am facing a problem like I have one **Vaadin ComboBox** with preselected value.I am changing the value from the **ComboBox** to another value,then **ValueChangeEvent** is fired.Inside the **valueChange** method I have written something to show a **Popup Window** which has **Cancel** and **Ok** button.Upon clicking on **OK** button of Popup Window I am going with the changed value of the ComboBox but upon clicking on **Cancel** button I just want to have the old value which was there before value change event fired.

Could anyone please help me out from the above issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can save whatever SelectedItem the combobox has when the event is fired, and if the user pressed cancel, you reset it to this stored item.

Comment: Thanks Godspark for your quick response. But my requirement is upon value change only I have to show the popup then clicking on ok button  I am doing some operation , but clicking on cancel button I don't wish to do anything but need to have the old value selected in the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

1. Before the click, how do you know what is selected in the click? Of course, you need to store the current selection somewhere. Lets call it currentSelectedValue (it could be NULL in the begining)
2. On click, you have a new selection, lets call it newSelectedValue
3. Now, if you do not want to go with this newSelectedValue, simply do this: 
   combo.setValue(currentSelectedValue);